# ORA-12899, while actual value length is smaller than maximum

Tags: oracle, ora-12899

I've loaded some data using SQL*Loader and obtained following strange error messages:

ORA-12899: value too large for column AELS_AENDBESCHR (actual: 69, maximum: 70)

ORA-12899: value too large for column AELS_AENDBESCHR (actual: 70, maximum: 70)

Actually the values don't exceed the maximum, so what the hell these messages are doing here then?

Comment: Multi-byte charecters may be?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11979495/409172   It might help if you post the control file, table DDL, and the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was in the character set of the database. I tried to put data supposed for  1 byte character set in a database with UTF-8 encoding, where german symbols "äöü" take 2 bytes instead one. I changed the character set using this [wikibooks](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Oracle%3a_CharacterSet_%C3%A4ndern) and now it works. The only problem is that I can't use APEX after it.